# How to avoid the axis jumping when the orientation is constrainted

Tags: ros, moveit, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Now the end-effector's orientation constraints is implemented in my offline simulation in Moveit. It can be seen that the orientation of end-effector is keeping horizontal to the ground. But during the motion, several axis of UR-10  jumps anyway. So do you guys know how to avoid the unexpected pose?

[video!!!!!!!!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GAVLup7PWE)

On the other hand, i am using Trac IK to UR-10  and the solve_type is inevitably set as 'speed', which has been changed as 'distance' in `kinematics.yaml`, when running the c++ code. Will this setting affects the axis jumping?

```
[ INFO] [1511333074.249636452]: Looking in private handle: /move_group_interface_tutorial for param name: arm/position_only_ik
[ INFO] [1511333074.250346507]: Looking in private handle: /move_group_interface_tutorial for param name: arm/solve_type
[ INFO] [1511333074.251106283]: Using solve type Speed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276447/how-to-avoid-the-axis-jumping-when-the-orientation-is-constrainted/) by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Late response but I believe this is related to a known moveit namespace issue, reported here: https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/issues/25

I resolved it on my system by adding the following code to my movegroup.launch file;

```
<group ns="move_group">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find MY_PACKAGE)/config/kinematics.yaml"/>
</group>
```

This ensured the correct solve type was used.

---

Originally posted by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) with karma: 147 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2018-01-10**:
yes, the parameters of kinematics can been correctly loaded when starting the launch-file. But after that, when i run a code with C++, it still change back to `solve type Speed`. You can see the last post in [link text](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/issues/25) in Nov is mine.

**Comment by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on 2018-01-10**:
Ahhh right, I see. I also added the same load command to my C++ launch file. That resolved the issue for me. It seems to be a namespace problem. If you ensure the parameters are loaded in the same namespace as your C++ component it should work.